# How to pass user role in the response while signing in with the help of Next Auth callbacks?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, callback, next-auth

Below is the code I need to modify

```
 export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
   adapter: PrismaAdapter(client),
    providers: [
     GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
       }),
  CredentialsProvider({
   name: "credentials",
   credentials: {
     email: { label: "email", type: "text" },
     password: { label: "password", type: "password" },
    },
    async authorize(credentials) {
     // check input
     if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password)
       throw new Error("Invalid credentials");

     // check user exists
     const user = await client.user.findUnique({
       where: {
         email: credentials.email,
       },
     });

     if (!user || !user.hashedPassword)
        throw new Error("Invalid credentials");

     // check password
     const passMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
       credentials.password,
       user.hashedPassword
     );

     if (!passMatch) throw new Error("Incorrect password");

     return user;
   },
     }),
  ],
   // callbacks: {
   //   async session({ session, token, user }) {
   //     console.log(session, token);
   //     return session
   //   }
   // },`your text`
 debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
 session: {
 strategy: "jwt",
 },
 pages: {
   signIn: "/signin",
 },
 secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
 };

 const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

 export { handler as GET, handler as POST };`
```

You can have a look at the code snippet above. I have tried using callbacks but it is not giving me the user role in any of these not in the callback session, token, or user.

Next Auth Version:    "next-auth": "^4.22.1",
Next Js Version  :    "next": "^13.4.7",`